# Determine all continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I don't really understand what is meant by the following problem when it is said "determine all continuous functions:"

Let $X$ be a metric space, and $Y$ be a discrete metric space.

1. Determine all continuous functions $f : Y → X.$
2. Determine all continuous functions $g : \mathbb{R} → Y.$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It means "find every function $f$ that is continuous relative to the topology here." That is, classify all functions $f$ such that whenever $O \subseteq X$ is open, we have $f^{-1}(O) \subseteq Y$ is also open.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: If $\{0, 1\}$ is equipped with a non-zero metric, e.g. $d(0, 1) = 1$, and $X$ is any metric space, then $\{0, 1\}$ has the discrete topology: Every set is open. So every map $\{0, 1\} \to X$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prove the following:

**Any** function from any discrete space to **any** topological space is continuous

The **only** continuous functions from the reals (with the usual Euclidean topology) to a discrete space are the constant ones (instead of "the reals numbers" you can put "connected top. space)